# Misleading data format Excel .csv

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, microsoft-excel-365

I am generating a .csv file with data like the example below:

```
TIME,LUX
18:00:00,30
18:00:01,30
18:00:02,30
18:00:03,30
18:00:04,30
18:00:05,30
18:00:06,30
18:00:07,30
18:00:08,30
18:00:09,30
18:00:10,30
18:00:11,30
```

When I open the Wordpad I see the data exactly like above, however, when I open it in Excel it changes to:

```
TIME,LUX
00:00,3
00:01,3
00:02,3
00:03,3
00:04,3
00:05,3
00:06,3
00:07,3
00:08,3
00:09,3
00:10,3
00:11,3
```

I would like to know what is happening and how can I avoid this to happen?

The Excel version is (Versão 2301 Build 16.0.16026.20196) 64 bits - Microsoft 365 MSO

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help). To have this kind of question answered you should provide more info. Create a sample document, upload both the .csv file and the Excel sheet to some file sharing service and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771548/edit) your question to put in the links. Your OS and Wordpad versions might also be relevant. Please don't answer in comments, editing your question to add info keeps it up-to-date and all the relevant data available.

Comment: Excel attempts to format columns when you open or paste data. In this case, it gave it an odd format. `A CSV file is NOT an excel file`. If you want to open in Excel, then format the column during the import process or after you have imported the data. In this case, I suspect you need to custom format such as `h:mm:ss`

Comment: You can import the .csv to Excel and format cells. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

Answer (score 1):

Again, this is a problem when you **OPEN** a csv file in Excel. It is always far better to **IMPORT** the file.

You can use either the legacy wizard or Power Query to do that.

If you are using the Legacy wizard, you can define the comma as the separator in step 2.

If you are using Power Query, ensure the comma is listed as the "delimiter"

Comment: there should be a community QA for this, shouldn't there?

Comment: @AlexM Probably, although since this type of guidance has been repeated many times in this forum and still overlooked by some, I don't know how beneficial it would be.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem : My Excel 365 open the `.csv` file correctly
when I double-click:

[image]

It's perhaps related to you regional format of time.
You may test by selecting some cells in the TIME column
(with time data, no text or empty cells), right-click any one of the
selected cells and click "Format Cells...".

Here is what mine looks like :

[image]

You may select the same format as mine to display in the same way,
or choose the "Time" format.